# NGINX rewrite switches directories

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, location

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
location ^~ /assets {
    rewrite_log on;
    rewrite ^/assets/(.*)/(.*)$ /websites/$host/themes/$1/assets/$2 break;
}
```

So, when I request `http://localhost/assets/theme1/css/style.css` I expect it to rewrite it to this:

`/websites/localhost/themes/theme1/assets/css/style.css`

Instead, it rewrites the request to this:

`/websites/localhost/themes/theme1/css/assets/style.css`

But, when I change the rewrite rule to:

`rewrite ^/assets/(.*)/test/(.*)$ /websites/$host/themes/$1/assets/$2 break;`

And I request `http://localhost/assets/theme1/test/css/style.css` everything works just fine.

Why does it switch `assets` with `css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I guess I got a bit confused about how regex works. ;) This works perfectly:

`rewrite ^/assets/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /websites/$host/themes/$1/assets/$2 break;`

I matched everything in `$1`, which was `theme1/css`, but because I only want the theme name, I have to exclude the `/` character. Thanks anyways for reading this!

Comment: Alternatively, you can make the first capture less greedy by using `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that also. :)